# Regular expression handle multiple matches like one, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex, and a string that includes some matches for this regex. My regex handle all this matches like it is only one big match (of course I don't want such behaviour), let me show you an example:

My test string (sorry for scribble, but this doesn't matter):

```
sdfsd -dsf- sdfsdfssdfsfdsfsd -sdfsdf-
```

my regex in js code:

```
view.replace(/(\-(.+)\-)/g, '<span style="background-color:yellow">$1</span>');
```

my result:

```
sdfsd<span style="background-color:yellow">-dsf- sdfsdfssdfsfdsfsd -sdfsdf-</span>
```

As you can see each of this strings in the "-" must be enclosed in span, but there is only one span. How I can fix this? (honestly I don't want change my (.+) regex part, which I think might be a problem, but if there is no other way to do this, let me know).

In other words, result must be:

```
sdfsd<span style="background-color:yellow">-dsf-</span> sdfsdfssdfsfdsfsd <span style="background-color:yellow">-sdfsdf-</span>
```

Feel free to ask me in the comments, and thanks for your help.

Comment: I have noticed that you don't want to change (.+), but it really seems the most simplest: (.+) -> (.+?)

Comment: @kasitan thanks for you comment, it's a really the simplest way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> honestly I don't want change my (.+) regex part, which I think might be a problem

Why not, it is actually the source of the problem, you can try the following regex which would work:

```
/(\-([^-]+)\-)/g
```

and if you think that dashes `-` can appear between `-` and `-` themselves then you can use the less efficient:

```
/(\-(.+?)\-)/g
```

`+?` causes a [lazy match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), or in other words after matching the initial `-`, then `.+?` matches a single character then it moves control to the following `-` which tries to match a dash, if it couldn't then `.+?` reads *(consumes)* another character from the input and so on until the following `-` is able to match.

Comment: Can you explain what this construction mean? `(.+?)`

Comment: I choose the second one because it's much clearer for me to understand and it efficient is not a priority in this task. It's a good lesson for me: don't be lazy with regex, better use lazy match :D Thanks a lot.

Comment: @flinth You are welcome, although I must **stress* that the first regex is much better if there isn't `-` between the two `-`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
view.replace(/-([^-]+)-/g, '<span style="background-color:yellow">$1</span>');
```